# Deployment synchronization across microservices

Tags: deployment, architecture, microservices

Let's say there are two environments: **staging** and **prod**.
There are also two microservices: **A** and **B**.
Microservices are already deployed to both environments and each running service version 1. So we have:

- staging: A1, B1
- prod: A1, B1

Now one development team implements new feature in microservice A (either synchronous API or async one through message broker) and deploys A2 to staging. Then another team implements new feature in B that makes use of new feature from A2 and also deploys it to staging (B2). Now we have:

- staging: A2, B2
- prod: A1, B1

New features are tested in staging environment by client and there are approved to be deployed to production. The question is how to determine which services should be deployed first to production. Obviously B2 must not be deployed first because it depends on A2. Are there any tools/strategies to keep track of it?

What I can imagine is that all services keep track on which versions of other services they depend and during deployment this versions are checked against what is running in target environment and if something is missing then deployment is rejected.

This raises a question - should microservice deployment be parallel or one-microservice-at-a-time?

Also what if, before deploying A2 and B2 to prod, there will be A3 released to staging and will depend on B2? Now we should schedule deployment to production like this:

A2 => B2 => A3

Those are real-world examples that come to my mind, but maybe in microservice architecture it's possible to avoid such situation following some rules?

Answer (score 2):

Versioning in integration points can be an option.

For example if microservice-A get an information from microservice-B through a REST call, when microservice-B wants to change integration (change in rest call contract for instance), microservice-B can add new endpoint with new versioned mapping like "/getInformationFromMeV2" without deleting old one. By this way when you deploy microservice-B, microservice-A can still use the old endpoint for a while. After deploying microservice-A too, you can remove old endpoint from microservice-B in next deployment.

Note: Of course if microservice-A wants to use newly developed endpoint from microservice-B, microservice-B must be deployed before microservice A.

---

For async communication you can still apply this approach. If you use broker based communication like using Kafka (suppose that you want to deploy microservice-A first):

- **If microservice-A is consumer**, then new topic is created and microservice-A subscribes the new topic too and new version is deployed for microservice-A. At that point microservice-A consume messages both from new and old topics (of course until microservice-B is deployed, all the messages will be sent to old topic) after microservice-B is also deployed, old topic is deleted.
- **If microservice-A is producer** again new topic is created and after deployment of microservice-A new messages are sent to new topic. When Microservice-B is deployed too, it starts reading messages from beginning of new topic and old topic is deleted.

With this kind of approaches you can deploy microservices independently as convenient to microservices architecture.